# How can I set up a VPN server on an EC2 instance that allows connected hosts to communicate

Tags: vpn

I teach an after-school program where we're using MIT App Inventor, which requires a  connection between the mobile device and laptop. The network at the facility uses isolation, which prevents devices from communicating with each other.

My idea was to set up a basic VPN server that the devices could connect to and then communicate on virtual LAN. I thought I might just spin up a cloud Linux server, but obviously I can't allow connected VPN clients to access anything outside of the server.

Is there a way to create a "virtual LAN" on the server with its own set of 192.168.0.* addresses, but are "jailed" to the sever (and of course still be able to access the internet)?

Comment: Introducing any addition complexity here is going to provide vey quickly diminishing returns. I'd recommend working with the network team to land on a mutually-agreeable solution that can be officially supported and understood by all involved.

Comment: I've already tried working with IT at the location. They said they can't disable isolation.

Comment: They're lying to you. They may not want to disable it, but I've not ever seen network gear on which you can't disable isolation.

Comment: To clarify, by "can't" they meant they can't do it without compromising their security. It's more of a policy thing, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private network that only your VPN server has access to. OpenVPN will create a TUN or TAP interface, and you can configure whatever address range you'd like for that interface to use. There is also a setting in OpenVPN that allows clients to communicate with one another.

However, I agree with EEAA that this is likely to become very messy very quickly, and I'd recommend trying to overcome the issues on the local network first.